# Why is my exposure indicator inaccurate?

Tags: exposure, metering

I own two Nikon D7100s, and right now the exposure indicators are off for both of them. They display a level of exposure, but it's not accurate. For instance, shooting in manual, with a Nikkor 18-105mm DX lens, at a shutter speed of 1/13s, f/4, I should be getting *tons* of overexposure. Instead, the meter is at 0, with no overexposure in the picture.

It's doing this for both cameras, where the exposure indicator doesn't match what the picture should look like. I've checked throughout the settings of the camera, and can't find anything in particular to correct this. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using auto ISO?

Comment: Ditto on the ISO question. Additionally: does the meter change at all if you change the settings? What metering mode are you using? And, can you post a few samples of the problem in different situations?

Comment: No. ISO is set at 100 for both of them. Yes, the meter changes as I move the settings. It's just shooting 'dark' at what should be normal levels, and normal at what should be overexposure. Metering is at Matrix for both, also.

Comment: Silly question - do you have any exposure compensation dialed in?

Comment: No, it's a fine question. As I rummage through the settings, I'm asking myself the same 'silly' things. The easy compensation setting was OFF for one camera, and ON for another, but both cameras were still weird with the exposure. It's odd. They shoot OK for a second, then not the next. I shoot on P mode, and it's still doing 'odd' things.

Comment: Can you try the other metering modes? What's in the scene?

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. I have to run some errands. Still open to suggestions, if any more comes up. Things were fine until this weekend. I did do some nighttime, long exposure shots. I don't know if this tidbit helps. All I know is these cameras shoot fine one second, then weird the next...mostly weird, though. I hope it's something simple that I'm just overlooking. Thanks again. Keep the suggestions coming.

Comment: Hmmm, also: you say *"I should be getting TONS of overexposure. Instead, the meter is 0, with no overexposure in the picture."* That seems to suggest that the metering is in fact correct, and your assumption that there should be overexposure is wrong. That is, the meter matches the results. Is that actually the case?

Comment: So you are taking a picture at 100 ISO, at second at f/4 and no exposure compensation... Is that 13 as in 1/13th of a second or 13" as in 13 seconds?  Even 13 seconds indoors at 100 ISO has a good chance of just being a gray mess.  Change the camera to P and take a photo and check the settings.

Comment: You said twice that the cameras shoot fine one moment, then weird the next. Do you have exposure bracketing turned on?

Comment: Do you have spot metering turned on?

Comment: Last resort option might be to reset the camera's settings, if it is a settings issue. (downside,  you'll need to reconfigure everything to your tastes)

Answer (score -1):

My guess- it could be the vignetting of the lens and maybe you are using evaluative metering (i.e. camera is taking readings from the areas that are vignetted)...

Comment: This doesn't seem likely. This is a DX lens on a DX body, both by Nikon. The is lens doesn't vignette to that extent. You'd need to have hard vignetting, like using a step-down ring with a smal filter, to get that much vignetting to significantly throw off matrix metering. Secondly, matrix metering more heavily weights (prioritizes) the focus point over the rest of the scene. There are no focus points in areas that are likely to vignette.